# Evaluate contents of string and match to tuple?

Tags: python, pandas, tuples, gis

I'm curating a dataset that was initially created poorly, using changing unique IDs for the same person,(changes per season). To consolidate their data into one dataset, I have created a csv that contains two columns that, when combined, identifies a unique individual.

Now I'm wanting to run Python code that searches a geodatabase and identifies the feature classes per unique individual. Problem is, my code stumbles at the part where I need to evaluate the second half of their unique ID:

```
import pandas, os, arcpy
gdb = r"D:\Segmented_GDBs\CleanedGPS_Boys.gdb"
walk = arcpy.da.Walk(gdb)

colnames = ['SID', 'age', 'gender', 'school', 'idsuffix']
df = pandas.read_csv(r'C:\Users\mlittl33\Desktop\Surveys_Boys_testsuffix.csv', names=colnames)
StudID = df.SID.tolist()
Schoollabel = df.school.tolist()
suffixer = df.idsuffix.tolist()

for root, dirs, files in walk:
    for fc in files:
        if fc.startswith(tuple(Schoollabel)) and tuple(suffixer) in fc:
            arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(os.path.join(root,fc))
```

It works as far as identifying the feature classes per Schoollabel, but fails at the *tuple(suffixer) in fc* portion.

The feature classes are structured like this: A1006_WD1
The csv is structured like this:
[Excel snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4W1a5.png)

Comment: What's the exception raised by your code?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 13, in <module>
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not tuple